# Trying to specify a default value for a dropdown with xslt?

Tags: xslt

My `record` nodes have a `@code` like `USA` and `label` like "United States".

```
<xsl:for-each select="/output/module/countries/data/record">
  <xsl:call-template name="option">
    <xsl:with-param name="value" select="@code"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="label" select="@name"/>
    <!--
         <xsl:with-param name="select" select="/output/module/formdata/data/record/billing_info/country"/>
    -->
    <xsl:param name="value" value="USA" />
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I'm trying to make `USA` the default value. Tried `with:param name="select" select="USA"` but that's a no go also. Hmm?

Ideally I'd like to have `USA` be the default if the other node specified in the comments doesn't have a value.

Comment: What version of XSLT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSLT 2.0, you can use an `if` in the `select`:

```
<xsl:with-param name="select" select="if (x) then x else 'USA'"/>
```

Just replace both instances of `x` with your xpath (`/output/module/formdata/data/record/billing_info/country`).

In XSLT 1.0 you can add an `xsl:choose` to your `option` template to test the value of the `select` param that is passed in. Something like:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="string($select)">
        <xsl:value-of select="$select"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:text>USA</xsl:text>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

You could put that `xsl:choose` in an `xsl:variable` if it's easier to use (like in attribute values or if you need to access the value multiple times).

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can do this in any version of XSLT:

```
<xsl:variable name="countryVal"
              select="/output/module/formdata/data/record/billing_info/country" />
<xsl:variable name="countryOrDefault"
          select="concat($countryVal, 
                         substring('USA', 1, 3 * not(normalize-space($countryVal)))" />
<xsl:for-each select="/output/module/countries/data/record">
  <xsl:call-template name="option">
    <xsl:with-param name="value" select="@code"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="label" select="@name"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="select" select="$countryOrDefault"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:for-each>
```